При открытии index.html просто черный экран
Хотел посмотреть игру "под капотом", и скачал с гитхаба все файлы.
https://github.com/Hexcein-moonsters/polytrack (c этого)
Открываю index.html, а там просто черный экран, хотя на гитхабе все работает (https://hexcein-moonsters.github.io/polytrack/     там просто на хост гитхаба выложили)
В чем может быть проблема?

Просто скачанный репозиторий не делает рабочим проект. Надо (судя по репозиторию) установить node.js, собрать проект, установить сервер redis, установить и настроить локальный веб-сервер. И только после этого пытаться запустить

ENGLISH:
Hello, I am the creator of the repository.
Opening the html file from the zipped repository gives a black screen because there are CORS issues. To run the game, you need to load it on a localhost or upload it to a https website to avoid CORS issues when it tries to load the Javascript file.
RUSSIAN:
Здравствуйте, я создатель репозитория.
При открытии html-файла из заархивированного репозитория появляется черный экран из-за проблем с CORS. Чтобы запустить игру, вам необходимо загрузить ее на локальный хост или загрузить на веб-сайт https, чтобы избежать проблем CORS при попытке загрузить файл Javascript.
